# How to know if a number belongs to a set in PHP?

Tags: php, range, belongs-to

I'll give an example, it's will be more straight to the point :

I'm working with coordinates and I want to filter the coordinates that do not belong to a set around the picked coordinate. Here for the latitude for instance :

```
$latitude = 4.3999291;
```

Basically, I have an array of latitudes, `$array_latitudes`, and I want to test each one to know if they belong to a range around `$latitude`.

What I've done so far :

```
$set = range($latitude-0.2, $latitude+0.2, 0.0000001);
foreach ($array_latitudes as $lat){
    if (in_array($lat, $set)){
        echo $lat;
    }
}
```

So the issue is, you guessed it, about the performance... It takes a really long time to create an array of values of a 10^-7 range !

My question, then, is : "Is there a simpler and more efficient way to return the latitudes in `$array_latitudes` which belong to the set [`$latitude`-0.2, `$latitude`+0.2] with a precision of 10^-7 ?"

Thanks all :-)

Comment: How do you ensure that $latitude has the right precision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not just test

```
if (abs($lat - $latitude) <= 0.2) {
  echo $lat;
}
```

?

Comment: The precision search is set to 0.0000001!

Comment: I fail to see why that is relevant.  It seems like the OP needs to know if the latitude being tested is within 0.2 of a given latitude.

Comment: Yes, was my misunderstanding!

Comment: Sometimes we look waaay to far ! Thank you for that elegant answer !

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something terribly,

```
if ( ($lat >= $latitude - 0.2) && ($lat <= $latitude + 0.2) )
    echo $lat;
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to do the reduce the array down to values that you're looking for.

```
class RangeFilter {
    var $lowerBound = 0;
    var $upperBound = 0;
    function RangeFilter($lowerBound, $upperBound) {
        $this->lowerBound = $lowerBound;
        $this->upperBound = $upperBound;
    }
    function filter($value) {
        return ($value <= $this->upperBound && $value >= $this->lowerBound);
    }
}

$latitude = 4.3999291;
$filter = new RangeFilter($latitude - 0.2, $latitude + 0.2);

$filteredCoordinates = array_filter($coordinates, array($filter, 'filter'));
```

But really, if you want to be simple:

```
$latitude = 4.3999291;
$lowerBound = $latitude - 0.2;
$upperBound = $latitude + 0.2;

$filteredCoordinates = array();
foreach ($coordinates as $coordinate) {
    if ($coordinate <= $upperBound && $coordinate >= $lowerBound) {
        $filteredCoordinates[] = $coordinate;
    }
}
```